# thread 1: exception: presentingviewcontroller must be set. (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement the google sign in button for my app in swift and I copied the code from the google dev website but whenever I run the app and click the google sign in button i get the "thread 1: exception: presentingviewcontroller must be set." error. My view controller is correct as it is the same to the google dev site code. Is something wrong with anything else?
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go2KY.png)

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
//import FBSDKLoginKit


@objc(ViewController)
// [START viewcontroller_interfaces]

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // [START viewcontroller_vars]
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signOutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var disconnectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusText: UILabel!
    // [END viewcontroller_vars]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        

          // Automatically sign in the user.
          GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()

         // [START_EXCLUDE]
          NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
              selector: #selector(ViewController.receiveToggleAuthUINotification(_:)),
              name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
              object: nil)

          statusText.text = "Initialized Swift app..."
          toggleAuthUI()
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        // [END viewdidload]
```

Answer (score 3):

Write one line of code
**GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self**
in **func viewDidLoad()**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to solve it I had to eliminate these first lines of code that are commented because it was executed before time. By eliminating those lines of code it worked perfectly for me I hope it works for you.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    /*
    if (userDefaults.bool(forKey: KeysUserDefaults.UsuarioLocal.esUsuario) == false)
    {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "FirstPage", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FirstSB") as? FirstPageViewController
        {
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    */
    
    // Intentamos iniciar sesion con los datos de userDefaults
    if (userDefaults.string(forKey: KeysUserDefaults.idToken) != "" && userDefaults.string(forKey: KeysUserDefaults.accessToken) != "")
    {
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: userDefaults.string(forKey: KeysUserDefaults.idToken)!, accessToken: userDefaults.string(forKey: KeysUserDefaults.accessToken)!)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
        { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error al intentar iniciar sesion de entrada")
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                // Mandamos al usuario a la pagina de Login/SignIn
                self.aRegistrarse()
            }else
            {
                // El usuario se cargo con exito.
                print("Nombre: \(authResult!.user.displayName!)")
                
            }
        
        }
    }else
    {
        print("Credencial del usuario vacia.")
        // Mandamos al usuario a la pagina de Login/SignIn
        self.aRegistrarse()
    }
    
    
}
```